# How do I return if let doesn't unwrap, using legacy swift

Tags: ios, swift

The guard line throws this error

> using legacy swift: Initializer for conditional binding must have
>   Optional type, not 'UIView'

```
private func animateDismissal(context: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {

   guard let containerView = context.containerView() else {
      return
   }
...
```

How do I return if let doesn't unwrap?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`context.containerView()` is not optional, so it cant be nil. So no need to `guard` or unwrap it.